# How can I participate in the Operation Portal Recon?

Tags: ingress

Some time ago Niantic announced that closed beta of the Operation Portal Recon is released.

- What are the conditions to participate in?
- Should I get an invitation or sign up to somewhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information below is no longer accurate.

> You may refer to [this blog by Tech
>   Crunch](https://www.google.com.hk/amp/s/techcrunch.com/2016/11/17/niantics-invite-only-portal-recon-tool-lets-players-vote-new-real-world-locations-into-ingress/amp/)
>   and [this article by Fev
>   Games](https://www.google.com.hk/amp/s/fevgames.net/operation-portal-recon/amp/).
>
> Basically, to join the Operation:
>
> 1. You must be
> 2. You must be L16 (no longer accurate as some agents with lower levels have received invitations as well. Thank you JamesENL)
> 3. You must be specially invited
>
>    Moreover, even when you have received an invitation:
>
> > Initially it appears that all L16 agents in the areas will be invited, however it’s not that simple. There will be a “training
> >     course” that the agent must take, as well as a test that must be
> >     passed, in order to prove that the agent “knows” what a good portal
> >     candidate is. If the agent fails the test they will not be eligible to
> >     participate until a later date (presumably after it leaves closed
> >     beta).
>
> If you fail to pass the test that Ingress provided, you will not be
>   able to participate in the Operation.
>
> You can sign in at the [OPR site](http://opr.ingress.com) if you are
>   invited. The Operation is in Closed Beta.
>
> As of May 11, 2017, OPR is available to any and all level 16 agents, referring to this official Tweet by Ingress: https://twitter.com/ingress/status/862434519642775554

As of June 13, 2017, OPR is available to any and all level 15 agents, referring to this official Tweet by Ingress:
https://twitter.com/i/web/status/874371248536596480

Below is the full message:

> Starting today, Operation Portal Recon (OPR) will now be available
>   globally to any level 16 Agent!! The portal network has grown from
>   those who helped calibrate Operation Portal Recon over the last
>   several months. We will be monitoring what effects that new Agents
>   evaluating Portal candidates will have on the Portal Network. In time,
>   additional Agents will gain access to OPR when we have determined that
>   Portal Network is not affected adversely. To access the system, go to
>   https://opr.ingress.com/.
>
> We want to thank all of the passionate Agents who helped us test the
>   system and perfect the algorithms. Together, these Agents reviewed
>   510,000 portals, rejected 67,000, and were responsible for 63,000 new
>   portals being created. To show our thanks, we are going to send a
>   special Operation Portal Recon T-shirt to the top 100 contributors. We
>   will send an email notice to the winning agents.
>
> In addition, there will be a new in game medal that can be obtained by
>   participating in Operation Portal Recon. It will be a tiered medal and
>   will not affect leveling up. More details will be announced soon about
>   this.
>
> ===Korean=== 오늘부터 Operation Portal Recon (OPR)은 전세계의 모든 16레벨 요원들에게 공개될 예정입니다!! 지난 몇 개월 동안 포탈 네트워크는 Operation Portal Recon에 도움을 주신 분들을 통해
>   성장해왔습니다. 우리는 포탈 후보를 평가하는 새로운 에이전트가 포탈 네트워크에 미치는 영향을 모니터링할 것입니다. 포탈
>   네트워크가 부정적인 영향을 받지 않는다고 판단되면 추가 요원들이 OPR에 접속할 수 있게 될 것입니다. 시스템에 접속하려면
>   https://opr.ingress.com/ 으로 이동하십시오.
>
> 시스템을 테스트하고 알고리즘을 완성하는 데 도움을 준 모든 열정적인 요원들에게 감사드립니다. 이 요원들은 X 개의 포탈을
>   검토하여 Y 개를 거부하고, Z 개의 새로운 포탈이 만들어지도록 수고해주셨습니다. 상위 100명의 기여자분들께 감사의 인사를
>   전하기 위해, 우리는 100명 모두에게 특별한 Operation Portal Recon T-shirt를 보낼 것입니다.
>
> 또한, Operation Portal Recon에 참여하여 얻을 수 있는 새로운 메달이 생길 것입니다. 이것은 등급 구분이
>   있는 메달이지만, 레벨 업에는 영향을 미치지 않습니다.
>
> ===Chinese=== 從今天起，審點系統OPR將開放予環球所有16級特工！有賴各位過去多月協力調試審點系統OPR，Portal的數量已有長足增長。我們將密切監察新一批審點員對Portal網絡的影響。隨著Portal網絡健康發展，我們將邀請更多特工參加審點。請在此進入審點系統：https://opr.ingress.com/
>
> 藉此良機，我們謹向所有曾參與封測的熱心特工致謝。這一眾特工同策同力，審校了 510,000 個Portal，駁回了 67,000個，並支持了
>   63,000個Portal的創建。為表示對其中100位最具貢獻者的謝意，我們將向他們送上特別版審點系統OPR紀念汗衫。
>
> 另外，參加審點將可得到新的成就勳章。這個新的分級勳章並不會算入特工升級的條件。
>
> ===Japanese=== 本日より Operation Portal Recon (OPR) は、レベル16のエージェント全ての方にお使い頂けるようになりました。ここ数ヶ月の皆様のご協力により、ポータルネットワークは大きな成長を遂げています。新しく参加されるエージェントの皆様がこのポータルネットワークへどのような影響を与えるのかを注視しています。懸念される影響がないことを確認した後、さらに新しいエージェントがOPRへのアクセスできるよう準備を進めています。OPRのシステムは
>   https://opr.ingress.com/ からアクセスしてください。
>
> このシステムをテストし、アルゴリズムを完成に導いて下さったエージェントの皆様へ感謝します。総計51万のポータルがレビューされ、6万7千のポータルが不承認に、6万3千の新しいポータルが承認されました。感謝の意を込めて、トップ100名の貢献したエージェントへ、Operation
>   Portal ReconのTシャツをお送りします。対象者へは改めてメールで連絡致します。
>
> また、新しくメダルを作成し、Operation Portal
>   Reconへ参加したエージェントへお送りします。このメダルは段階的なものですが、レベルアップには影響しません。詳細については後日発表致します。
>
> ===German=== Ab heute ist das Operation Portal Recon (OPR) für alle Level 16 Agenten verfügbar. Das Portal-Netzwerk ist durch Agenten
>   gewachsen, die geholfen haben, das Operation Portal Recon anzupassen
>   und zu verbessern. Wir werden genau beobachten welchen Effekt neue
>   Agenten auf das Portal-Netzwerk ausüben. Im Laufe der Zeit erhalten
>   zusätzliche Agenten Zugang zum OPR, wenn wir festgestellt haben, dass
>   das Portal-Netzwerk nicht nachteilig beeinflusst wird. Um auf das
>   System zuzugreifen, besucht https://opr.ingress.com/.
>
> Wir möchten uns ebenfalls bei allen begeisterten Agenten bedanken, die
>   uns geholfen haben das System zu testen und den perfekten Algorithmus
>   zu finden. Gemeinsam haben diese Agenten 510.000 Portale überprüft,
>   67.000 abgelehnt und waren dafür verantwortlich, dass wir 63.000 neue Portale generiert haben. Als Dankeschön werden wir den Top 100
>   Mitwirkenden ein spezielles Operation Portal Recon schicken. Wir
>   werden eine Nachricht an die jeweiligen Agenten schicken.
>
> Zusätzlich wird es ebenfalls eine neue Ingame Medaille geben, die man
>   durch die Teilnahme am Operation Portal Recon bekommt. Diese Medaille
>   wird keinen Einfluss auf das Leveln haben und verschiedene Tiers
>   besitzen. Mehr Details dazu werden in Kürze bekannt gegeben.

Comment: Actually, I'm Level 15, was holidaying in Japan in February and I got an invite. So there's something off about your answer.

Comment: I'll clarify that in the question.

Comment: Answer outdated: see following one.

Answer (score 2):

As this post https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/hPZFqa7Q4qs states you must be Level 12 or above agent. You will not get any invitation but when you go to https://opr.ingress.com/ you will allow to take the selection test. But first you must study https://opr.ingress.com/help (As I remember you will get this https://opr.ingress.com/training first but since I passed opr redirects to home) There are video from ADA and below video in detail explained documentation of training. I recommend you should watch both carefully. Because Documentation has more details. After that take the test. you will be face 10 mcq problems. We can't say what is precise Passing marks but surely it's not 10/10 ;) it might 8/10. In case of you failed the test you'll get the chance to face it after 30 days time. Good Luck and join with us to shape the future of Ingress :D

Comment: @Attalos First of all please point out why you gave me minus please? I'm 100% confident I am giving currently (23/07/2017) correct Information. I think you must confused word "shape the future of Ingress". If you have OPR worthy Ingress player you must know We get review reject bad portal and approve good ones. So please don't bring ignorance resistance mindset place like StackOverflow where we #SOReadyToHelp 
Clearly you seems unable to appreciate when someone trying to help

Comment: What you wrote is correct. [+1] for me.

Comment: Thanks, @Sampisa I appreciate your comment. Because It's so sad to see that people being biased by faction and without logical answer :)

Comment: Well I didn't realize / think that, to be honest. Indeed, it's totally useless - and IMHO also quite stupid - to bias answers or votes thinking to the faction, religion, ethnicity or what else. :)