# Is the seer badge continue to count if a new portal submit accepted on Operation Portal Recon?

Tags: ingress

Operation Portal Recon (OPR) is [available now](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/301857/83172) for Level 12 or above agents  ([As NIA mentioned in here](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/hPZFqa7Q4qs) 
This will be the last level granted access at this time
). Many agents started to vote for portal submissions.

After a portal submission accepted and placed to scanner by NIA, will that portal submission be added to its submitter's seer badge?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but here are some informations:

https://fevgames.net/operation-portal-recon-available/

> Great! So how long until I can finally submit again? Will they reopen seer?
>   That is not known at this time, unfortunately.  John Hanke has previously stated that portal submissions are a critical part of the game, so we can assume that this will come back eventually.

But later in the comments a guy wrote this:

> I can confirm from my Agent-stats.com history that the new portals approved count towards the Seer medal.
>   I had 18 and with the 2 portals I got approved in the last 15 days I finally got to 20! \o/
>   I hope it keeps growing! :D

So it seems, yes.

**EDIT**

Our local leader told me, yes, it is count. Based on experience.

Answer (score 4):

[image: Seer badge info modal showing portal count greater than badges awarded]

I feel there is a lot of bad info here.  The answer is NO! And yes...  Yes your count will continue to go up however you will not be able to unlock the badges themselves.

https://plus.google.com/+MarcinCwikla89/posts/QVErAZd9UpK

Comment: This image would be more useful if you trimmed it down to just the badge popup and explained what we're seeing.  E.g. "See the count is up to 53 but it didn't provide the 50 badge."

Comment: It seems all accepted portals are counted for the number (the 53 above). But only those submitted before end of 2014 are take into account for the badge. (Which ist quite confusing. Thanks, Niantic!)